# Cannot run app after updating SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, es6-promise

I made an update to the SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin and it now has a new dependency on this plugin es6-promise-plugin.

The issue I am experiencing is that when I try to load the app I receive an error:

```
Error: Module es6-promise-plugin.Promise does not exist.
```

in this function of the native file

```
function addEntry (strategy, moduleName, symbolPath, opt_deprecationMessage) {
    if (!(moduleName in moduleMap)) {
        throw new Error('Module ' + moduleName + ' does not exist.');
    }
    symbolList.push(strategy, moduleName, symbolPath);
    if (opt_deprecationMessage) {
        deprecationMap[symbolPath] = opt_deprecationMessage;
    }
}
```

This es6 plugin was added automatically and I didnt change anything about it.
Should I note the dependency somewhere else as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Dependent plugins should be installed automatically without your intervention if the plugin.xml has correctly specified it, check the file and look for the dependencies section.